# Titanium - Changes done to TableViewRow custom properties aren ignored

Tags: android, properties, titanium, tableview, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working with Titanium SDK 2.1.3 and developing for both iOS 6.1 and Android 4.0.

My application has a TableView, each TableViewRow represents a file and has a custom property called lockedStatus that can be either true or false, when a row is clicked, depending on the value of lockedStatus, a window is opened indicating the state of the element of the row. In this window I can modify the lockedStatus from true to false and viceversa.

The problem I'm having is that in Android the changes done to this property are ignored, unless a completely force the application to stop, this doesn't happen in iOS.

To change the lockedStatus value in the window, I fire an event like this:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('updateLockedStatus', {
    lockedStatus : true //this can be true or false
});
```

Then the listener is like this:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('updateLockedStatus', function(e){
    var rows = table.data[0].rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) //iterate through the rows to look for the file
    {
        if (rows[i].fileID == currentlyEditingFile)
        {
            rows[i].updateLockedStatus(e.lockedStatus);
            files[currentlyEditingFile].lockedStatus = e.lockedStatus; //update the file lockedStatus
            rows[i].fileObject = files[currentlyEditingFile];
            saveFilesToDatabase();
        }
    }   
});
```

Each row is generated with a updateLockedStatus function, that has the following definition:

```
row.updateLockedStatus = function(lockedStatus)
{
    row.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;
}
```

The saveFilesToDatabase function looks like this:

```
function saveFilesToDatabase()
{

    var tempFilesArray = [];

    for(var i=0;i<filesIds.length;i++)
    {
        tempFilesArray.push(files[filesIds[i]]);
    }

    Ti.App.Properties.setString('filesApp', JSON.stringify(tempFilesArray)); //save the file values in the application properties
}
```

What I mean by being ignored is that when I exit the window and return to the view with the table of files, if I click again on the file I just modified, the window will be opened as if no change had been done.

How can I force an update for all of the contents in the TableView? In iOS there's no problem, but with Android this isn't updated unless I close the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Ti.API.fireEvent` & `Ti.API.addEventListener` instead of `Ti.App`

Comment: The app doesn't start at all if I use T.API.fireEvent/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

you would take care when doing this :

> Each row is generated with a updateLockedStatus function, that has the following definition:

```
row.updateLockedStatus = function(lockedStatus)
{
    row.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;
};
```

If the code above is put in a loop then executing the *row.updateLockedStatus* may affect only the last row because the *row* variable gets reused and contains at the end only the last *row* object. Take a look at [this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)

You can simply use this code :

```
row.updateLockedStatus = function(lockedStatus)
{
    this.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;  // this is the current row
};
```

Or using closures, something like that :

```
row.updateLockedStatus = (function(r){

    return function(lockedStatus){

        r.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;   // r is the current row

    };

})(row);
```

the local *r* variable should retain the right row object.

BTW, when you listen events using Ti.App, you should use variables for handlers. Instead of doing this :

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('updateLockedStatus', function(e){
```

use this way

```
var updateLockedStatusHandler = function(e){
    //...
};

Ti.App.addEventListener('updateLockedStatus', updateLockedStatusHandler);
```

Then this could be useful to remove the handler and avoid a potential memory leak :

```
Ti.App.removeEventListener('updateLockedStatus', updateLockedStatusHandler);
```

Comment: I previously tried to use `this.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;` and also tried using closures, but got the same result. I'm using Ti.API.info to see if the correct row and file are being updated and they are, but for some reason, when I go back to the window with the table, the changes aren't taken into account. I was considering to enforce a complete update on the table by firing another event but that didn't work to, it's like the original settings persist somehow.